# WP Redirect From /%postname%.html To /%category%/%postname%/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, plugins, permalinks

I changed my WP permalinks from " **/%postname%.html** " , not the more common " **/%postname%/** " to currently " **/%category%/%postname%/** ". WP handles this just fine. But i am having problems redirecting old URL's to the new structrue. I have tried several redirect plugins, but they only seem to redirect if the old structure was the most common " **/%postname%/** ".

I get 404 errors when i try to open old URL's in browsers unless i add " **RewriteRule (.+).html$ /$1/ [L,R]** " to .htaccess to first change URL's from **/xxx.html** to **/xxx/**. The problem i want to fix is that although everything works fine, i have a total of 2 redirects to get to the final and correct " /%category%/%postname%/ ". Pagespeed Insights shows this as a landing page redirect problem i should fix. Is there a way to correct this in .htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being I don't use Nginx redirects, I use this

```
add_filter( '404_template', 'custom_redirect_to_category' );

function custom_redirect_to_category($template) {

    if ( ! is_404() ){
        return $template;
    }

    global $wp_rewrite;
    global $wp_query;

    if ( '/%category%/%postname%/' !== $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure ){
        return $template;
    }   

    if ( ! $post = get_page_by_path( $wp_query->query['category_name'], OBJECT, 'post' ) ){
        return $template;   
    }

    $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
    exit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done with this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/

Comment: I see nowhere to add redirects from old permalink structure to new., I do not want to add redirects one page at a time.